# Can I generate an unsigned APK using dexguard?

Tags: android-studio, apk, proguard, dexguard

My question is quite simple but it seems I cannot find the answer on the web and since dexGuard does not have a trial period I cannot test it myself.

Can I generate an unsigend apk obfuscated/encrypted with dexguard in Android Studio. I've been told that is not possible because the signature is used during the obfuscation/encryption process but I feel like I'm missing something.

I would like to know if I can obtain the same result I obtain with "assemble release" gradle task with proguard enabled but using dexguard instead for a better protection.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, you can. This answer does not depend on unsigned/signed and release/debug. I'm able to build my dexguard-enabled APKs in all the 4 cases.

Answer (score 1):

Dexguard is a better version than Proguard so it has all the functionalities that has its little brother. From the Dexguard docs:

> The procedure for building Android applications and libraries **remains
> the same**. You can invoke gradle with the usual targets, such as
> assemble, build, install, and connectedInstrumentTest. For instance,
> to build the release version of your application and install it on a
> connected device:
>
> gradle installRelease
>
> To build the release version of a library:
>
> gradle assembleRelease
>
> Debug builds use debug settings, without
> optimization or obfuscation. Release builds use release settings, with
> full optimization and obfuscation. Applications can **optionally** be
> signed. The entries in application archives are always zip-aligned for
> efficiency.

Additionally you can use the Standalone version which makes DexGuard run from the command line. By using this you can post-process an existing Android application (.apk file).

I only use Dexguard to obfuscate a Library in Standalone mode but I am pretty sure it will work.